# Why NSView leaves an image on superview on where it was when I move it?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

I am working on a small application on Mac that I need to create customed cursor and move it. I used NSImageView to implement it. However when I call setFrameOrigin (the same to setFrame) it will leaves images on the previous place.
Here is my code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSImageView *eraserView;
```

this is the define

```
_eraserView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 32, 32)];
_eraserView.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"EraserCursor"];
[self.view addSubview:_eraserView];
[_eraserView setHidden:YES];
```

here is the initialization. Everything goes well until now but:

```
- (void)setImageatPoint:(NSPoint)point
{
    [_eraserView setFrameOrigin:point];
}

- (void)hidePenImage
{
    [_eraserView setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)unhidePenImage: (BOOL)isEraser
{
    [_eraserView setHidden:NO];
}
```

These are methods I use to change the state of the NSImageView. They will be called by another class using delegate when corresponding events of trackpad occurs.
However every time I change the state of the NSImageView, it seems like it is drawn on the superview.
I debugged it and found there was no extra subviews. And when I use setHidden it has no effect on those tracks. I think it somehow did something to the CALayer, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots would help but in general if you move a view or change the area of the view that is drawn, you need to redraw. 
To do this it kind of depends on how  your drawing happens. Calling setNeedsDisplay may not be enough if your implementation of drawRect only draws a sub rect of the view bounds.  Cocoa only draws what it is told to draw. 
You can erase sections of the view that should be empty by drawing (filling) where it should be empty. That means drawing a color ( NSColor clearColor if nothing else) in the area that was previously drawn.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to upload screenshot. But it is easy to imagine that every time I setFrame to a new place, a replica image will stay where it was. And I didn't do anything in drawRect. I only added the NSImageView as subview to a NSView. I do not think I should do anything about drawing about it if I only wanna to change the position.

Comment: In fact, not only setFrame. Even if I call setHidden:NO to let it appear, a "permanent" image will be left on the superview.